# Configure Pagelets/PivotGrids in a WorkCenter Dashboard

Tags: peoplesoft

I am new to developing Work Center Dashboards in PeopleSoft so I have experimented with my own sandbox to learn more. One thing I have not figured out is how / where to configure the pagelet/pivot grids that I added from the "Manage WorkCenter Dashboards" page. I've added the PeopleSoft delivered pagelet for "PO Spend Analysis As Of" and "Dispatched Purchase Orders" however when I actually view the work center I get no data returned, and I do not see an option for adding/changing filters for them (even though there is a filters panel).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What People tools and patch version you are on? There is an issue with 8.55.11 and below

You have to be in PT8.55.12 and above.

BUG:26554509 - E-PIA: DRAGGING TO PIVOT GRID TO APPLY FILTER CAUSES BLANK SCREEN